# Trying to use an actionButton to get next random image nested within random tab

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

### The problem

I am building a shiny app with a questionnaire, about dogs breeds and living spaces. And for the questions each dog breed appears in a tab in a random order, and within those tabs I show different houses where you could have those dog breeds.

The main idea is to randomize both the dog breeds (by tab) and each of the housing possibilities nested within that tab.

### What I have so far

This is my best working example so far in a [working shiny app](https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/Survey/) and all the files and scripts are in [this github repository](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/QuestionaryApp) so you can clone it to test all the example code

In this app the tabs do show on random order (by breed). The first house option also shows well, my idea is that when you press the *next house* action button it shows the next random house without repeating (it is important that the person answering does not see the next house beforehand for them not to be influenced by that)

I have tried two different approaches to this problem included in the github repository in the folders *FirstTry* and *SecondTry*.

#### First try

This is the working shiny app, here is the code for it, working in this [link](https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/Survey/) and with the code in this [link](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/QuestionaryApp/tree/master/FirstTry)

Here is the code of the ui which is really simple, just a tabpanel with the uiOutput *mytabs* which contain all the tabs:

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = tagList(
        navbarPage("",

                   tabPanel("DogImages",
                            fluidRow(
                                column(width = 6,
                                       uiOutput('mytabs')
                                ) )

                   )#cerrado tab panel 2

        ) #cerrado de navbar Panel    

    ), #cerrado ui
```

Then the server is where all the magic happens

```r
    server <- function(input, output) {


        #####################################
        # Tabs breeds

        ## This renderUI generates each tab with a lapply
        output$mytabs = renderUI({

            ## I have three breeds
            Breeds <- c(1:3)

            ## And then create a random order of them
            Random <- sample(Breeds, 3)

            #### And now loop through each random breed
            myTabs = lapply(Random, function(i){

                ### Starts with the first random breed
                tabPanel(paste("Breed", i),

                         ###
                         fluidPage(
                             fluidRow(
                                 column(6,
                                        wellPanel(
                                     ###Here it sources random breed i    
                                            img(src = paste0("Dog",i, ".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300))),
                                 ##then within that I want to have the
                                 ##Random houses but here is where I run 
                                 ##into problems
                                 renderUI({
                                     ##Starting with random habitats
                                     Habitats <- c(1:3)
                                     RandomH <- sample(Habitats, 3)


                                     ## The idea is that I use this new button to show the next house
                                     column(6,actionButton("New_Button", "Next house"),
                                            wellPanel(
                                                uiOutput(paste0("PlotHouse",RandomH[1])))                                     )

                                 })
                             )
                         ))
                ####
            })


            do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
        })
```

and this is just the source of each house and closure of the server and shiny:

```r
        output$PlotHouse1 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House1.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })

        output$PlotHouse2 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House2.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })

        output$PlotHouse3 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House3.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })


    }

) #Close shiny app
```

So this works for dog breeds but not for not , and I have to make the *next button* to show the next random house, which is what I try to do in the folder *SecondTry*

#### Second try

for this one I change the code within the second renderUI within the lapply:

```r
renderUI({Habitats <- c(1:3)
          RandomH <- sample(Habitats, 3)
           ### Here I add the reactive value j = 1 to move the RandomH along
          Values <- reactiveValues(j = 1)
         ###This is to show j just for the question
          output$Numb <- renderText(Values$j)
    ### Here I state that every time I press new button it adds 1 to j
          observe({input$New_Button
                   isolate(Values$j <- Values$j + 1)
                   })
          ## and this is the action button for next house  
          column(6,actionButton("New_Button", "Next house"),
                 textOutput("Numb"),
                  ## Here I say show me img PlotHouse[j]
                 wellPanel(uiOutput(paste0("PlotHouse",RandomH[Values$j])))
                           )

           })
```

### Expected solution

Just that when I press the next house button I see the next random house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides storing the counting in reactive values the main challenge would be to differentiate between tabs: Two ways come two mind.

- Using modules
- Listen on tab changes.

To count the clicks simply use `reactiveValues()`.

```
global <- reactiveValues(nr = 1)    

observeEvent(input$New_Button1, {
  global$nr <- min(global$nr + 1, maxHouseNr)
})
```

In order to reset the counter when switching to the new tab you want to listen on tab changes. You could give the `tabsetPanel()` an id and listen on `input$ID`.

Set id:

```
do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id = "whichTab", myTabs))
```

Listen on tab change:

```
observeEvent(input$whichTab, {
  global$nr <- 1 
})
```

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
maxHouseNr <- 3
Habitats <- 1:maxHouseNr
RandomH <-lapply(rep(maxHouseNr, 3), sample, size = maxHouseNr, replace = FALSE)


shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage("",

               tabPanel("DogImages",
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 6,
                                 uiOutput('mytabs')
                          ) )

               )#cerrado tab panel 2

    ) #cerrado de navbar Panel    

  ), #cerrado ui

  server <- function(input, output) {


    global <- reactiveValues(nr = 1)    

    observeEvent(input$whichTab, {
      global$nr <- 1 
    })

    observeEvent(input$New_Button1, {
      global$nr <- min(global$nr + 1, maxHouseNr)
    })

    observeEvent(input$New_Button2, {
      global$nr <- min(global$nr + 1, maxHouseNr)
    })

    observeEvent(input$New_Button3, {
      global$nr <- min(global$nr + 1, maxHouseNr)
    })


    #####################################
    # Tabs breeds

    output$mytabs = renderUI({
      Breeds <- c(1:3)
      Random <- sample(Breeds, 3)
      myTabs = lapply(Random, function(i){


        tabPanel(paste("Breed", i),

                 ###
                 fluidPage(
                   fluidRow(
                     column(6,
                            wellPanel(
                              img(src = paste0("Dog",i, ".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300))),
                     renderUI({

                       column(6, actionButton(inputId = paste0("New_Button", i), "Next house"),
                              wellPanel(
                                uiOutput(paste0("PlotHouse", i)))
                       )

                     })
                   )
                 ))
        ####
      })


      do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id = "whichTab", myTabs))
    })

    output$PlotHouse1 <- renderUI({
      img(src = paste0("House", RandomH[[1]][global$nr],".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300)
    })

    output$PlotHouse2 <- renderUI({

      img(src = paste0("House", RandomH[[2]][global$nr],".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300)
    })

    output$PlotHouse3 <- renderUI({
      img(src = paste0("House", RandomH[[3]][global$nr],".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300)
    })


  }

) #cerrado de shiny
```

Comment: That works great, thanks @BigDataScientist !!, I would like as you call it heterogeneous randomness across tabs for houses if you could work that out that would be awesome, I still will award you the points in a few hours, but if you could work that out it would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the random order into reactive values and trigger the calculation by the button in a reactive enviorment (ojala sea esto lo que quieres)

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = tagList(
        navbarPage("",

                   tabPanel("DogImages",
                            fluidRow(
                                column(width = 6,
                                       uiOutput('mytabs')
                                ) )

                   )#cerrado tab panel 2

        ) #cerrado de navbar Panel    

    ), #cerrado ui

    server <- function(input, output) {

        Breeds <- c(1:3)
        Values =reactiveValues()

        #####################################
        # Tabs breeds
        observe({
            input$New_Button
            Values$Random <- sample(Breeds, 3)
        })

        output$mytabs = renderUI({
            myTabs = lapply(Values$Random, function(i){


                tabPanel(paste("Breed", i),

                         ###
                         fluidPage(
                             fluidRow(
                                 column(6,
                                        wellPanel(
                                            img(src = paste0("Dog",i, ".jpg"), height = 300, width = 300))),
                                 renderUI({
                                     Habitats <- c(1:3)
                                     RandomH <- sample(Habitats, 3)

                                     column(6,actionButton("New_Button", "Next house"),
                                            wellPanel(
                                                uiOutput(paste0("PlotHouse",RandomH[1])))
                                     )

                                 })
                             )
                         ))
                ####
            })


            do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
        })

        output$PlotHouse1 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House1.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })

        output$PlotHouse2 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House2.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })

        output$PlotHouse3 <- renderUI({
            img(src = "House3.jpg", height = 300, width = 300)
        })


    }

) #cerrado de shiny
```